# Use Python Interpreter inside Jar

Tags: java, python

I have written a Java application that calls a python script using runtime. In order to make this application portable, I have included a python interpreter in the JAR when I compiled it in Intellij. However, the runtime isn't using this version of python so I was wondering if there was a way to get the file path of this python interpreter so that I can run the script.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to access a file inside a .jar (a zip archive) as if it was a regular file? Not possible in any easy or portable way. Yoi'd have to extract the file, then use the extracted copy.

Comment: Is there anyway to use a python interpreter as a resource in the jar?

Comment: what do you mean - did you seriously include a cpython binary in your jar file? or do you mean you have included a python script file in the classpath and want to run it with an external python interpreter? If you just want to run a simple script which you've included in your jar you can try using jython - https://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html you could then just use `new PythonInterpreter().execFile(getClass().getResourceAsStream("myscript.py"))` to execute it.

Comment: @herbert I can't use jython because I'm using python 3. I've got a python script in the resource folder and I am trying to include a python interpreter as part of my jar distribution so I can run the application on computers that don't have the correct python libraries already installed

Comment: If it is a binary that needs to be executed by the operating system, then it must exist as a file in a file system visible to the OS. Easiest way is to extract it, either to temp folder every time, or just once under the application folder, if it is missing or changed.

Comment: And before you ask: Mounting contents of a .jar (.zip) as a file system is not practical solution for an application which needs any kind of portability (and if it doesn't need portability, why are you doing it with Java anyway?).